# Getting DB error: data type mismatch in criteria expression c#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Pretty new to c# and db programming.  And I've taken over somebody else's code.  I'm getting an error when I'm trying to update the DB.  Here's the code:

```
   private void EnableEvent(int eventID)
    {


        OleDbCommand oleCMD = new OleDbCommand();
        oleCMD.Connection = Database.SqlConn();
        OleDbTransaction oleTrans = oleCMD.Connection.BeginTransaction();
        oleCMD.Transaction = oleTrans;

        try
        {
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.AppendFormat("UPDATE Events SET isActive = 1 where EventID='{0}'", eventID);

            oleCMD.CommandText = sql.ToString();
            // insert the header
            oleCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oleTrans.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Database Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            oleCMD.Connection.Close();
            oleCMD.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the complete error string ?

Comment: how do I get any more of the error string?  e.message is "Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression"

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Gotcha now ... format your query like below and it would surely work

```
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.AppendFormat("UPDATE Events SET isActive = 1 where EventID = {0}", eventID);
```

With `Numeric` fields yiou shouldn't put apostrophes around the value. That was the problem.

Comment: eventID is an int... I double checked.

Comment: did you tried the query format I proposed in my answer ... just quote the `set isActive = '1'` and try once. should work fine.

Comment: I did.  No luck. What command would I use in my MySQL Workbench to try it manually?  I know how to run a SELECT query from a database.  But how do I run a UPDATE?  This way I can see if the database will even take the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
private void EnableEvent(int eventID)
{
    OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(myConnString);
    myConn.Open();

    OleDbCommand myCommand = myConn.CreateCommand();
    OleDbTransaction myTrans;
    // Start a local transaction
    myTrans = myConn.BeginTransaction();
   // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction
    myCommand.Connection = myConn;
    myCommand.Transaction = myTrans;

    try
    {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.AppendFormat("UPDATE Events SET isActive = 1 where EventID='{0}'", eventID);

        myCommand.CommandText = sql.ToString();
        // insert the header
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myTrans.Commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Database Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        myCommand.Connection.Close();
        myCommand.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!